# join with count on a joined table with group clause in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 tables:

- applications (has many votes)
- votes (belongs to applications and questions)
- questions (has many votes)

I need to get number of votes per application per question.

So, my attempt was:

```
SELECT applications.id, COUNT(votes.id), votes.question_id
FROM applications
LEFT OUTER JOIN votes ON (votes.application_id = application.id)
GROUP BY votes.question_id
```

However, it displays data only for a single application, so I assume my query is malformed:

```
+----+-----------------+-------------+
| id | COUNT(votes.id) | question_id |
+----+-----------------+-------------+
|  1 |            1185 |           1 |
|  1 |            1170 |           2 |
|  1 |            1209 |           3 |
|  1 |            1230 |           4 |
|  1 |            1213 |           5 |
+----+-----------------+-------------+
```

What I need:

```
+----+-----------------+-------------+
| id | COUNT(votes.id) | question_id |
+----+-----------------+-------------+
|  1 |            1185 |           1 |
|  1 |            1170 |           2 |
|  1 |            1209 |           3 |
|  1 |            1230 |           4 |
|  1 |            1213 |           5 |
|  2 |            null |           1 |
|  2 |            50   |           2 |
|  2 |            333  |           3 |
|  2 |            1230 |           4 |
|  2 |            1213 |           5 |
|  3 |            null |           1 |
|  3 |            50   |           2 |
|  3 |            333  |           3 |
|  3 |            null |           4 |
|  3 |            5555 |           5 |
+----+-----------------+-------------+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `group by` clause was missing `applications.id`.

```
SELECT applications.id, COUNT(votes.id), votes.question_id
FROM applications
LEFT OUTER JOIN votes ON votes.application_id = application.id
group by applications.id, votes.question_id
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be grouping by the `applications.id` as well as the `questions.id`:

```
SELECT a.id, COUNT(votes.id), votes.question_id
FROM applications a LEFT OUTER JOIN
     votes v
     ON v.application_id = a.id
GROUP BY a.id, v.question_id;
```

However, this will not produce exactly what you want. You seem to want all the questions for the applications, regardless of whether or not there are any votes.  If so, this is probably what you want:

```
SELECT a.id, q.question_id, COUNT(v.application_id)
FROM applications a CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT DISTINCT question_id FROM votes) q LEFT JOIN
     votes v
     ON v.application_id = a.id and v.question_id = q.question_id
GROPU BY a.id, q.question_id;
```